# Randomise and Order Divs - Slick.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using the [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) library and have the following lines of code on my web page, which will allow me to randomise the order of the slides in the carousel.

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$('.qa').on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    // Randomize the slides and then run slick slider
    $.fn.randomize = function(selector) {
        var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
        $parents = $elems.parent();

        $parents.each(function() {
            $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
                return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
            }).detach().appendTo(this);
        });

        return this;
    };

    $('.qa').find('.slick-track').randomize('.slick-slide');
});
```

As I'm not very familiar with JavaScript/jQuery, how would I be able to randomise the order of my slides (which it currently does) ***except*** for the very last one (which would be in its order)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

slick.js adds a clone of some of the slides, for this reason I would recommend that you randomize the slides before you call `slick()`.  You can also keep your code almost exactly as you have written it but add one check to prevent the last slide from being reordered*.  Checkout the included example.

```js
$.fn.randomize = function (selector) {
    var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
        $parents = $elems.parent();

    $parents.each(function () {
        $(this).children(selector).sort(function (childA, childB) {
            // * Prevent last slide from being reordered
            if($(childB).index() !== $(this).children(selector).length - 1) {
                return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
            }
        }.bind(this)).detach().appendTo(this);
    });

    return this;
};

$(".qa").randomize().slick();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.6/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.6/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="qa">
    <div>your content 1</div>
    <div>your content 2</div>
    <div>your content 3</div>
    <div>your content 4</div>
    <div>your content 5</div>
    <div>your content 6</div>
    <div>your content 7</div>
    <div>your content 8</div>
    <div>I am always last</div>
</div>
```

If you inspect you will see that the last slide is always last.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting an array of all but the last entry, randomizing it, and then pushing the last entry onto the new array.

On how to shuffle, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Assuming the laxt entry is the one you still want to display last, you can (pseudocode)

```
var array = [allmyelems];
var last = array.pop();
shuffle(array);
array.push(last);

function shuffle(array) {
    //function from above link
}
```